# Google Chrome audio seeking and buffering

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, audio

When trying to play the MP3 file Google Chrome first loads audio file from the start to the seeking point and only then starts playback from the seeking point. How to tell Chrome to disable buffering useless piece of audio file and play the audio from the seeking point immediately, without buffering from the start?

I have an `audio` tag in the root `body`. There are no any attributes except `id` — no `src`, `type`, etc. — completely empty `audio` tag.

I have a lot of `players` (Angular directives) which uses this one `audio` tag for playback (so, when I navigate to the other site's page audio will not stop).

Each `player` has its own seekbar — I can click the seekbar to start the audio from any time. The playback of the audio starts immediately in all latest browsers... well, not in Chrome — Chrome first preloads missing audio chunk from the start to the seeking point and only then plays the audio.

There are some screenshots of the requests I've made — Chrome and FF (here each player was set `currentTime` to play from 25:01 minutes in the seekbar):

Chrome first GET request (when the `audio` tag gets the `src` attribute):
[image: Chrome first GET request]

Chrome second GET request (when the `audio` tag sets `currentTime` to 25 minutes):
[image: Chrome second GET request]

Firefox first GET headers (when the `audio` tag gets the `src` attribute):
[image: Firefox first GET request]

Firefox second GET request (when the `audio` tag sets `currentTime` to 25 minutes):
[image: Firefox second GET request]

So, when the `audio` gets the `src` it sends first GET request to load some metadata and other info. Then it sends second GET request because of audio `currentTime` change.

By default Chrome always sends «Range: bytes=0-» header with the first request, nothing can change it. (FF sends «Range: bytes=491520-» with the first request.)

So, what I'm doing wrong? Maybe I need some more headers from the server response? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a Chrome regression, this has become broken as far as our team can tell today/yesterday in the latest Chrome stable release.

If you take a look at SoundCloud it too has this problem today.

Previously if you had a Xing header in the audio file it would fix it and properly seek, but its stopped working.

Comment: Well, in Chrome Canary version 47 it behaves the same :(